# React js - Unable to use react-icons, Module not found '../lib'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-icons

This is my first post on stackoverflow so I will try my best to keep it short, sweet, and detailed enough to hopefully find some assistance.

I'm currently trying to learn React js and when I try to install `react-icons` and import an Icon, my dev server is just crashing.

1. `npm install react-icons`

   **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "ecostrategy",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
```

2. In my code I put:

```
import { FaGithub } from "react-icons/fa";
```

3. `npm run start`
   Failed to compile.

> ./node_modules/react-icons/fa/index.esm.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve '../lib' in 'D:\name\school\semester\class\project\node_modules\react-icons\fa'

4. I've also tried `npm install react-icons --save` and based on the error saying it can't resolve '../lib' I even just took a guess and tried `npm install lib` which didn't work. Uninstalling and reinstalling `react-icons` didn't help either.
5. I deleted my `node_modules` folder and ran `npm install` again, this didn't fix the problem. My output after running `npm install` was:

> added 1987 packages from 789 contributors and audited 1990 packages in 103.053s
> 153 packages are looking for funding
> run `npm fund` for details
> found 3 moderate severity vulnerabilities
> run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

When I try `npm audit fix` it says something about not being able to solve them automatically, and `npm fund` gives me just a list.

Comment: Try wiping your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` at root of your folder. Then check if the issue persists

Comment: @geralt0 I updated my issue above, unfortunately it still persists

Comment: In this file that you are using the import statement, is it located at the root of your project or in a folder such as `src`?

Comment: Is there a build step before you run `npm run start`? If so, what are you using to build the project (e.g. babel, webpack, etc)?

Comment: @geralt0

I am using the import statement in `LoginComponent.js`

`D:\name\school\semester\class\project\node_modules`
`D:\name\school\semester\class\project\src\components\LoginComponent.js`

Comment: @Cully If I understood the react tutorial correctly... I'm not currently building and deploying this project (?) That would be creating a build folder. I am running this locally on a developer server deployment.

Comment: What gets run by `npm run start`? Are you using something like create-react-app or Next.js?

Comment: @Cully This is what you're looking for, I think
`"start": "react-scripts start",` is what's in my `package.json`

Comment: What version of node and npm are you using?

Comment: Btw, yes, that's what I was hoping to find (`react-scripts start`). Looks like you are using create react app.

Comment: @Cully 
node: `v14.17.7`
npm: `6.14.15`

Comment: I think I found what's causing the issue. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there's a problem with react-icons v4.3.0. See this issue: https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons/issues/490

The solution is to downgrade to v4.2.0. Try setting this line in your package.json:

```
"react-icons": "4.2.0",
```

Then remove `node_modules` and run `npm install` again.

This essentially "pins" the version of `react-icons` to `4.2.0`. It will never install another version. So, you'll want to keep an eye on the package. I'm sure a fix will be pushed soon. After that you can set the version back to `"^4.3.0"` (or `"^4.4.0"` if that's the fixed version) and see if it's resolved.

**UPDATE:** Apparently this has been fixed in `react-icons` v4.3.1. So you can set this line in package.json back to:

```
"react-icons": "^4.3.1",
```

Comment: It worked!! This is the solution, I'm amazed. Thank you SO much, I literally was searching the internet for hours and couldn't find a similar issue. Truly amazing, thank you for taking the time and making my first post on Stackoverflow a great experience :)

Comment: The issue was only posted 11 hours ago. It probably hasn't shown up on search engines yet. If you encounter something like this in the future for a specific package, visit the github page for the package and search the issues (try searching the closed issues too if you don't find something). Sometimes you'll find answers you wouldn't find from Google or Stackoverflow.

Comment: It's likely other people will have this same issue and find your question here. You were just unlucky enough to be the first person to ask :) But thanks for posting a question; it will help others until the maintainers fix it!

Comment: How funny is that. Very valuable information right there, I wouldn't have even thought of that to be honest with you. I really appreciate the guidance, I've definitely learned a lot today!